# Find a (constant) matrix $A$ for all $x,y,z$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following problem and I don't know what it is asking me to find.

Find a constant matrix $A$ so that

$$\begin{equation}
A
 \begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  z
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  2x+y\\
  x-y-z\\
  5z
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$$
This is a linear algebra problem. I understand that the matrix will be composed of numbers and no variables, but I don't understand what constrains me from picking any values for $x, y$ or $z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let 
$$A =  \begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
We should find the above coefficients, such that

\begin{equation}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  x\\
  y\\
  z
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  2x+y\\
  x-y-z\\
  5z
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Expanding the RHS, we get
\begin{equation}
 \begin{bmatrix}
  a_{11}x + a_{12}y + a_{13}z\\
  a_{21}x + a_{22}y + a_{23}z\\
  a_{31}x + a_{32}y + a_{33}z
 \end{bmatrix}
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  2x+y\\
  x-y-z\\
  5z
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
By identification of coefficients, we get
\begin{align}
 a_{11} &= 2 \\
 a_{12} &= 1 \\
 a_{13} &= 0 \\
 a_{21} &= 1 \\
 a_{22} &= -1 \\
 a_{23} &= -1\\
 a_{31} &= 0 \\
 a_{32} &= 0 \\
 a_{33} &= 5 
\end{align}
That is
\begin{equation}
 A
 =
 \begin{bmatrix}
  2 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & -1 & -1 \\
  0 & 0 & 5 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: Oh god wow. Thank you so much for your very detailed explanation of something so obvious ( or should have been obvious to me haha).

Comment: Glad it was helpful .. if you found it helpful, you could mark the answer as correct and upvote it so that others know it was helpful :)